# Add sounds on touch screen

Tags: javascript, audio, indexof

I do an app for a public touch screen.
 I have to insert sound/voice to help users on first pages of each parts.
I use indexOf function on Url. 
But I would like the voice just on first page.

For example the "information" page, 
I have got in my `url : "[...]index.php?state=information"`.
 So I use `window.location.href.indexOf(«state=information»)` in JS:

```
function playSounds(){

        var obj = document.createElement('audio');
        obj.volume=0.10;
        obj.autoPlay=false;
        obj.preLoad=true;     
        …
        var information = "state=information";
        …
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(information) > -1){
            obj.src="/sounds/Menu_information.wav";
            obj.play();
        }
        …
}
```

But logically the voice also play when url is `"[...]index.php?state=information&pageinfo=2"` for example.

But maybe I have everything wrong...
What other method or function could be used to put sounds just on home page of each parts without repetition?

Thank you in advance,
Evy.

Comment: Can you not just check that the index of pageinfo is -1 as well as the check you're already doing?

Comment: Use `/state=\w+$/.test(window.location.search)` or something like this (more specific) in addition to the first check.

Comment: Thinking about it, if you may have more parameters, you could just check if there is an '&' in the href, then you know there are two parameters

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the additional parameter `&pageinfo=2`.

```
var url = 'index.php?state=information&pageinfo=2';    
var matches = url.match(/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]+/gi);
    var count = matches? matches.length : 0;
    if( count == 1 )
      // play the sound
    else
      return false;
```

Give this a try (:

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! At the end I just add a check on "&" element as said George.
Because i don't have just one or two parameters. I can have 10 parameters for each state and I can't test them one by one.
But thank you for your solutions. These are good ideas that I could reuse.

(It's not really professional but it's functional ^^)

```
 if (pathname.href.indexOf(information) > -1){
        if (pathname.href.indexOf("&") == -1){
             obj.src="/sounds/Menu_information.wav";
             obj.play();
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```